# Copper zone not completed filled

Tags: kicad, copper-pour, gnd-pour

I designed a board using KiCad 7. After connecting all the signal nets, I tried to place a copper zone. This copper zone is generated, but it is not completed filled:

[image]

I tried to modify the properties and priority of the zones, but nothing has solved this problem. I made several boards using KiCad 5 and nothing like this has ever happened. Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like a stand-off from the edge of the board and/or fill zone.

Comment: Or some restrict areas from an errant footprint.

Comment: Might there be (or were there) any Zone Cutouts used? Did you recently move components out of the areas that are now showing the problems? Have you tried doing an "Unfill Zone" followed by a "Fill Zone"? Maybe even try those steps along with an exit and restart of KiCad. Also be sure to set the Remove Island parameters as needed in the zone's properties to reduce or eliminate unconnected fill pieces. You also seem to have some component items/edges disabled, you should enable all layers and objects to verify other possible reason for the zone problems.

Comment: It also looks like you still have many unconnected wires.

Comment: FYI, pouring VCC is generally not a good idea; prioritize pouring and stitching GND both sides, instead. Use local bypass to handle VCC supply. The problem is you can't make both top and bottom pours contiguous, and stitching both is a huge pain and very fragile to maintain

Answer (score 2):

The zone clearance and minimum width are specified separately from track and pad. Select a zone, right click and select properties. Set the values here. Also, small islands can be automatically removed. The island size can be specified.

[image]